# Send/share option goes to sending a new email page in Gmail app by default

Tags: applications, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-nexus, bluetooth

Whenever I try to send an application to another android device via bluetooth, when I hit the button "send" it opens a new message in gmail app and the application I wanted to send via bluetooth is attached there. How can I change this so that it asks how I would send that file/app? I 
have astro installed as a file manager.

[image]

Comment: Where is this "send" button you mention? In some app somewhere?

Comment: As @DanHulme says there usually isn't a 'send' button, there can be a 'share' button but for obvious piracy reasons, apk files aren't often included in this. It is unclear from the question what you want to do, and how you are trying it? Is it Astro file manager that has this optioni? Have you tried another file manager?

Comment: @RossC: There's no such button. The one which is more likely to be intended for sending/sharing purposes is the "send"  button.

Comment: Share button: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html This has been in android for several years. Are you using a third party application? Here is a pic of the 'share' button in action: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gn8nnLC70Xc/TrFoY1GxKtI/AAAAAAAAAEI/6UDPHv-Zxv8/s1600/sharelist.png Here is the ICON for the share button: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MVMEg.png I assume you are trying to 'send' it via Astro file manager, which (I haven't tried it in a while) does not allow you to send an apk file as it is a piracy risk. Can you post screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: @RossC: Yes, the phone is rooted. My Galaxy nexus doesn't have a file manager, so I have no choice other than using a third part app.

Comment: Ok, that's grand. Have you tried this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2015187 That should take care of it, especially since you are rooted! Let me know how you get on! (Note that you will use the 'Share' button as per the images I posted above as you are following the steps in XDA)

Comment: Yeah, what you posted links to is for images and pictures or some other kinds of files. But to send an .apk file via bluetooth, you should go to the folder containing it and use an option there.

Comment: The one I posted is titled sending an APK. Did you read it? You have to backup the app. You can't just navigate in and send it over bluetooth, as I said that is blocked as a piracy risk! The first line reads: This is a tutorial on how to share an android Application(Apk) via bluetooth.

Comment: @RossC: I was replying to your other comment, in which you posted a link on what the button looks like. a friend of mine has another model of Samsung Galaxy and sends/shares app quiet easily. I've Googled it myself before asking here and nothing worked. Anyway, I will give it(the instructions in the aove link) a try, thanks.

Comment: Yeah some devices are just easier than others, sometimes you have to go down the XDA route and try the long workaround. We've unraveled the confusion anyway. From what I can tell that 'SEND' option seems to be specific to a particular file manager (Astro in this case), and not an android default. The old 'share' should work on a backup. You MAY be able to do it with root directly in ES file explorer, but I haven't tested that myself. EDIT: ES file explorer has a 'Send' button for apk AND a 'Share' button, just to confuse matters. Try it first, then the XDA post I guess!

Answer (score 1):

There must be a "**Share**" option, which you can use to send via `Bluetooth`, `Whatsapp`, `Wifi direct` etc..

Comment: Possibly not for an apk file? Older android used to share a link to the app on the Market (now Play Store) but not the actual apk itself.

Comment: @RossC of course, you can send/share `.apk` file (or any **other type**  file) through Bluetooth! (at least in `ES File Explorer` or `Root Explorer` or `Astro File manager` etc,.)...

Answer (score -1):

As for Galaxy Nexus 2, one must use a third party application to transfer files via Bluetooth, since it basically doesn't have a file manager and a third party file manager like ASTRO don't let you transfer files via Bluetooth.